# Raster clipping error with GRASS

Tags: grass-gis

I'm using GRASS 7.6 to clip a raster (i.e. big_raster) layer on a smaller one (i.e. small_raster).
Both the rasters are made by nan and 1 values.

I used the map calc tool

```
r.mapcalc expression="raster_clipped = if( “small_raster@PERMANENT” , "big_raster@PERMANENT" )"
```

Why do I get this error?

```
Invalid map <“small_raster@PERMANENT”>
Parse error
ERROR: parse error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/grass76/gui/wxpython/gui_core/goutput.py",
line 473, in OnCmdOutput

self.cmdOutput.AddStyledMessage(message, type)
  File "/usr/lib/grass76/gui/wxpython/gui_core/goutput.py",
line 771, in AddStyledMessage

self.AddTextWrapped(message, wrap=None)
  File "/usr/lib/grass76/gui/wxpython/gui_core/goutput.py",
line 720, in AddTextWrapped

txt = EncodeString(txt)
  File "/usr/lib/grass76/gui/wxpython/core/gcmd.py", line
99, in EncodeString

return string.encode(_enc)
UnicodeDecodeError
:
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 27: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1-You have unnecessary quotes in your expression. No need to quote the map names. So:

```
r.mapcalc expression="raster_clipped = if( small_raster, big_raster)"
```

2-However,I think this is **not** what you want. This expression will not clip your big raster. You will get a **new raster of the same size** with values only where the small raster is not null. If you want to clip, then set the region to the small raster and then a simpler mapcalc expression:

```
g.region -p rast=small_raster
r.mapcalc expression="raster_clipped = big_raster"
```